# Completeness with distance functions in metric space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, complete-spaces

Let *S* be a set and let *d* and $\tilde d = \frac d{1+d}$ be two  distance functions on *S*. Prove that if *S* is complete with distance *d*, then *S* is complete with distance $\tilde d$.

Comment: Formatting note:  to put a tilde on something like d use the syntax "\tilde d".  You can click on "edit" above to see the exact syntax I used in editing your post.

Comment: Start by showing that, if $(x_n)$ is Cauchy with respect to $d$ then it is also with respect to $\tilde d$ and vice versa.